# Type 'TestHotObservable' is missing the following properties from type 'Subject<any>': observers, closed, isStopped, hasError, and 5 more

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, ngrx

I am trying to implement simple unit test on effect. I am trying to implement code from this example:
https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/docs/effects/testing.md
but unfortunately i cannot compile the code because of authActions. This line:

```
authActions = hot('--a-', { a: action });
```

Gave me compilation error like:

> Type 'TestHotObservable' is missing the following properties from type
>   'Subject': observers, closed, isStopped, hasError, and 5 more.

**Here is code snippet:**

```
import { AuthEffects } from "./auth.effects";
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { provideMockActions } from '@ngrx/effects/testing';
import * as AuthActions from './auth.actions';
import { hot, cold } from 'jasmine-marbles';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';

describe('AuthEffects', () => {
    let authEffects: AuthEffects;
    let authActions: Subject<any>;

    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [
                RouterTestingModule
            ],
            providers: [
                AuthEffects,
                provideMockActions(() => authActions)
            ]
        });

        authEffects = TestBed.get(AuthEffects);
    });

    it('effect test', () => {
        let username = '';
        let password = '';
        let role = 'PARENT';
        const action = new AuthActions.TrySignin({ username, password, role });
        const completion = new AuthActions.SigninUser()

        authActions = hot('--a-', { a: action });
        const expected = cold('--b', { b: completion });

        expect(authEffects.authSignin).toBeObservable(expected);
    })
})
```

Since I am newbie with this I am out of ideas. What might be wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

You have to define the actions as an Observable - https://ngrx.io/guide/effects/testing

```
let actions: Observable<any>;

...

 it('should work', () => {
    actions = hot('--a-', { a: action });;
  });
```